Limits on single RDS Instance running Postgres
In a single RDS instance(t4g & m5) running Postgres(15.x or above), what are the limits on number of databases I can create & number of schemas per database? If I exceed limits, can I request quota increase for both of them?

I don't think there is any; other than the technical limitations of postgres itself

This is what the docs are for FAQ: How many DB instances can I run with Amazon RDS?

@AdrianKlaver FAQ talks about RDS instances not databases per instance.

Oops. selected wrong line. Just below the above is How many databases or schemas can I run within a DB instance?

Hidden in AWS RDS FAQ section: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/

